# Having change array output format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that's used to create labels in order to make them printable. There is a sheet that takes the amount of labels needed and creates the labels in the format of

[data, data, data]

[data, data, data]

I have a script that takes that and pushes it into an array but is it possible to make this array output in the format of either

[data, null, data]

[data, null, data]

or

[data, data]

[data, data]

this is to allow the sheet 'Labels Clean' to be able to print onto the sheet of labels that we have.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx").getSheetByName("Labels Dirty");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx").getSheetByName("Labels Clean");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var Paste = [];
  
  for(var n = 0; n < data.length; n++)
  {
    if(data[n] != "")
    {     
      Paste.push(data[n]);
    }
  }

sheet2.getDataRange().clear();
sheet2.getRange(1,1,Paste.length,Paste[0].length).setValues(Paste);

Logger.log(Paste);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to skip the second element( with index `1`),  ignore it when you push:

```
Paste.push([data[n][0],data[n][2]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

Your goal is to convert the 2D array returned from `getValues()` to 1D array but also remove the empty values/cells.

- You don't need a for loop and in fact it will be really inefficient as the input data increases.
- You can use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert the 2D array into 1D and then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the empty cells:

  `var Paste = data.flat().filter(r=>r!='');`

**Solution:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx").getSheetByName("Labels Dirty");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx").getSheetByName("Labels Clean");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var Paste = data.flat().filter(r=>r!='');
  Logger.log(Paste);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, after trying this approach it isn't what I'm looking for. 
The array is pasted into the clean label sheet in 3 columns but I need it to paste in only 2

Comment: It is pasted in 3 columns because the input data is 3 cells (excluding blank cells). How exactly do you want to paste 3 cells in two columns? [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65192243/edit) your question and be more specific. I would advice you to share a screenshot of the input and a screenshot of the expected output. That will eliminate confusion and it will help me help you out. @Index

Answer (score 0):

```
function reorganizinglabels() {
  const sheet1=SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx").getSheetByName("Labels Dirty");
  const sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx").getSheetByName("Labels Clean");
  //const sheet1=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  //const sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const data=sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  const cols=2;//number of columns in the output
  let oA=[];
  let row=[];
  data.flat().filter(e=>e).forEach((l,i)=>{
    if(i%cols==0) {
      if(i>0){oA.push(row);}
      row=[];
      row.push(l);
    }else{
      row.push(l)
    }
  });
  if(row.length>0) {
    while(row.length!=cols) {
      row.push('No Label');
    }
    oA.push(row);    
  }
  sheet2.clearContents();
  sheet2.getRange(1,1,oA.length,cols).setValues(oA);
}
```